# how does webpack config.js files work?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I cloned a [repo](https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files) that has a starter boiler plate for a react redux project and notice that there are we setting files - 
1. webpack.config.dev.js
2. webpack.config.prod.js
3. webpacksettings.js

What is the difference between these files? I'm guessing one is used for the dev build and one is for the prod build, but what's the point of the 3rd one if the first two signify the settings already?

Comment: I can only the the first 2 here : https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files/tree/master/learn-redux
Can you point me on the third's one location ?

Comment: sorry i think someone else added that and i got confused

Comment: No problem, question solved ;-)

Comment: What you can often see, though, is a "base" webpack.config.js that is imported by others dev/prod/... config files as a common config, and derived from ...

Comment: I'm not seeing that and I ask this question originally because I'm able to see the gif and specialized font when I'm using a devServer with the webpack.dev.js settings but it's not working when I built out the the bundle through the webpack.config.prod settings and just open the index.html on my browser. So I'm trying to figure out if the problem is with the webpack.config's or if it has to do with hosting it locally through a server or not. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497635/hosting-webpack-through-devserver-js-vs-opening-index-html-on-browser-directly for more details